# How can I include a parameter along with a request body when calling a third-party POST API using HttpClient in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I have an http post api which calls another third party post api. I need to send 1 parameter which contains ip address along with request body while calling this third party api. I am using HttpClient's PostAsync method. Below mentioned is the code that I have used. In this how do I pass parameter?

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MyAPI(MyAPIModel oMyAPIModel)
        {
            var serializedJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oMyAPIModel);
            StringContent httpContent = new StringContent(serializedJSON, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            return await PostAsync("ThirdPartyAPI", httpContent);
        }
```

```
  public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(string requestURI, HttpContent httpContent)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddres);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                string authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(username + ":" + password)); //("Username:Password")  
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authInfo);
                httpResponseMessage = await client.PostAsync(requestURI, httpContent);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logging.SendErrorToText(ex);
        }
        return httpResponseMessage;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must know what is the fields the third party API expected to get with the request.

Then create a class with properties has the same name, like this:

```
    public class ApiRequestClass
    {
        public string IpAddress { get; set; }
        //Add all you want here 
    }
```

Then create a new instance of this class and assign the values of its properties and create the httpContent.

```
ApiRequestClass apiRequest = new ApiRequestClass
                {
                    IpAddress = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString(),
                    //Asign other properties if there is any
                };
var serializedJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(apiRequest);
StringContent httpContent = new StringContent(serializedJSON, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Finally send the request.

```
httpResponseMessage = await client.PostAsync(requestURI, httpContent);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Ibrahim! But I passed the parameter as a query string. It was so obvious but it didn't clicked in the first place may be because, I felt that since it is a post, I cannot pass it as a query string.

httpResponseMessage = await client.PostAsync(requestURI + "?" + "sourceIP=" + sourceIP, httpContent);